# How do I import something from a module in a folder with a string?

Tags: python, string, module, python-module

How do you import something from a module in a folder using a string. I have tried to use the **__import__** statement. And also the library: **importlib**. I just don't really understand how to use it. Here's what I'm trying to do:

```
/folder
    questions.py

__init__.py
app.py
```

In the questions.py there is a dictionary called math_questions with it's questions and answers. How do I import questions.py from app.py using a string?

Comment: Why not just use `import folder.questions`? The `__init__.py` should be placed in `folder`.

Comment: What does it mean "using a string"?

Comment: For example if there was multiple files in /folder and the user could decide what file the user wanted to import. Using input() for example. EDIT: And yeah the __init\__.py is in there too. Forgot to write that. Sorry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to SO!

Create an empty `__init__.py` file in your folder directory.

Then in app.py do: `from folder import questions` or `import folder.questions as questions`

Suppose questions.py has a method or variable called foo, you can then use it as follows:

```
print(questions.foo())
```

or if its a variable:

```
print(questions.foo)
```

For python3: if you want to import a file using a string, you could use exec (make sure that you trust the input)

```
lib_to_import = input('Which module to import?')
exec('import %s' lib_to_import)
```

For python2:

```
import importlib
lib_to_import = input('Which module to import?')
mod = importlib.import_module(lib_to_import)
```

Comment: I know that. But using a string

Comment: Updated my answer.